# How to make upi payments on iphone node.js (upi://)

Tags: javascript, html, url, payment-gateway, upi

I use these urls for my upi payments

```
upi://pay?pa=upi@id&am=100
```

I use these links for payments in my website^^

But if you try to open the link on iPhone, it doesen't give user the option to open which upi app they want to?
How to fix it?
I want it to open Paytm by default

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anay

upi://pay?pa=upi@id&am=100

Use Below Links

Phonepe://upi/pay?pa=upi@id&am=100

paytm://upi/pay?pa=upi@id&am=100

gpay://upi/pay?pa=upi@id&am=100

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: app opened but payment not completed

Comment: UPI intent only work with the Merchant Account, Tested on Phonepe Business merchant and HDFC smart hub vyaapar